# Better way to write common function with parameter is different class

Tags: list, c#-4.0

In my project, I have some functions like that:

func 1 (with 2 class: class1 and classs1_1):

```
List<class1> GetData1(class1_1 cls)
{
    List<class1> list = new List<class1>();
    cls = new cls();
    //do something for cls, like cls.GetSpecialCase();

    //fill data from cls to list, as using foreach to fill data to list

    return list;
}
```

func 2 (with 2 class: class2 and classs2_2):

```
List<class2> GetData2(class2_2 cls)
{
    List<class2> list = new List<class2>();
    cls = new cls();
    //do something for cls, like cls.GetSpecialCase();

    //fill data from cls to list, as using foreach to fill data to list

    return list;
}
```

How could I write a function like that (because I don't want to use a lot of functions as above):

common func (with T is class1, object cls is class1_1):

```
List<T> GetData(object cls)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    //how to recognize which class of cls
    if(cls == class1_1)     class1_1 other_cls = cls as class1_1;
    if(cls == class2_2)     class2_2 other_cls = cls as class2_2;
    //do something for other_cls 

    //fill data from other_cls to list
    return list;
}
```

I just want to pass parameter as object, and in the common function, I want to know which class I'm passing to so that I can treat to right class, and call right function.

Anyone helps me to solve this problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need:

- An interface or abstract base class with the `GetSpecialCase` method
- A generic method (with type parameters for both input and output) of

  ```
  List<TResult> GetData<T, TResult>(T item) where T : ISpecialCase<TResult>
  {
      List<TResult> list = new List<TResult>();
      var other = item.GetSpecialCase();
      // Fill list via other
      return list;
  }
  ```

If you can't introduce an interface or base class, you *could* use dynamic typing, but I'd strongly recommend that you use polymorphism to express what the different classes have in common (`GetSpecialCase` here) if you possibly can.

Comment: hi Jon, thanks for your helps quickly. But please look again my func 1, I use T and T1 (two different classess)

Comment: @Langthang: T1 doesn't appear anywhere in your question. Which class are you talking about? It's very unclear what your objection to my solution is... partly because you haven't provided a short but complete example of the problem. (If you had, I could give you a short but complete example of the solution, which I could verify more easily...)

Comment: please see again my quesion, at func1, I upated that I used 2 classes: Class1 to return, Class1_1 is parameter. Same for func2 (class2 and class2_2)

Comment: @Langthang: Ah, I see. It *really* doesn't help when you have class names like that - it also really doesn't help that there *still* isn't a short but complete example. Will edit.

Comment: @Langthang: I've edited the answer. If that still wouldn't work for you for some reason, you *must* give us a short but complete example so that we can find avoid having to get information out of you one comment at a time. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hi Jon Skeet, your help is definately help me a lot. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use generics also for the input type.
your code could be something like:

```
List<T> GetData<T>(T cls)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    //no need to recognize which class of cls

    //do something for other_cls 

    //fill data from other_cls to list
    return list;
}
```

and both classes needs to implement the same interface so you wouldn't need to know which type it is...

Comment: Thank silver for quickly help. But I use two difference classes (Class1 and Class1_1). Please review.